# Two steps comment form

Tags: comment-form

Is it possible to have a comment form for anonymous users, that be proceeded in two steps. First step enter author info (Name and Email) then second step to add comment?

I know this is possible with AJAX (with some limitation). Also some plugins like Jetpack, does something close to that, and Gravity have a multi-step function but only for login form.

But I am trying to do that without a plugin, so what I did so far is I have created two form:

- first form (for logged in users) that has only comment field.
- second form (for non logged in users) that has name and email fields only.

That doesn't seem applicable since it is requiring logging in, which is not the approach here. And Ajax limitation here, that the second form will always require comment field to be filled.

So do I have to change the second form to be a registration form? Or can I accomplish that with comment form?